# Is there a way to get quater end dates in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In MS SQL Server is there way we can get only quarter end dates? Something similar to below screenshot.

[image]

I do not have any underlying table as such to which I can reference, hence looking for generic SQL code which would fetch this data.

I'm sure this would be very useful function especially for people in financial markets.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop over all valid dates and execute below code and insert into the temp table

```
SELECT  DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, @AnyDate) + 1, 0))
```